# Function return void in PHP 7

Tags: php, return-type, php-7

PHP 7 adds support for return type declarations:

```
function sum($a, $b): float {
    return $a + $b;
}
```

Is there anyway to declare a procedure? (a function without a return)

```
function printLn($a): void { // <-- TypeError
    echo "$a\n";
}
```